# From this parameter is it possible to get target element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If we have structure like below

```
<div id="level1" onclick="customfunction(this)">
    <div id="level2">
        <span id="element1">E1</span>
        <span id="element2">E2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above structure when i click on element1 . this parameter will give whole div object. where as if i need to know on which child it is clicked, what need to be used i.e similar to event.target.id  / event.currentTarget? **with out passing event as a paramater in the function**

Comment: `with out passing event as a paramater in the function` No. Some browsers have a global `event` object, but Firefox is the exception to that. A better alternative would be to use an unobtrusive event handler, although the event is still provided as a parameter to the handler function

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: yeah i am using jquery

Comment: Why couldn't you bind click event using relevant unobstrusive method then? And so, why don't you want to pass `event` to handler parameter?!...

Comment: those are predefined functions added by the standalone application

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Jquery you could do:

```
$('#level1').on('click', 'span', function () {
    //now `this` refers to the span being clicked
});
```

Please check this fiddle I have made: http://jsfiddle.net/uupbvapa/

Hope it helps!